# Vertical table with Bootstrap/AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a table which is displayed properly on mobile devices.
To achieve this, I'm thinking about arranging the headers vertically like:

```
Header1 Information1
Header2 Information2
Header3 Information3

Header1 Information1
...
```

So, as you can see, I have to use ng-repeat so that everything from my data gets displayed.
This is my code for the table so far:

```
table class="table table-hover table-striped" class="ergTable" id="mobileTable">
        <div class="mobileErgDiv" ng-repeat="data in responseData | limitTo:limit">
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <td>{{data.title}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Komponist</th>
                <td>{{data.komponist}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Instruments</th>
                <td>{{data.instruments}}</td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </table>
```

The problem is, that no data gets display as a result of a non-working ng-repeat. I guess it's not possilbe to repeat a div in a table? That's because I have also tried to change the div to a tr, with the same result.

I would appreciate every possible solution.
Greetings,
Force0234

Comment: You can use ng-repeat-start="data in responseData | limitTo:limit" on the first tr and then use ng-repeat-end on the last to do what you are trying to do without the div. But I'm not sure that's going to get you what you want. You may need to transform your data to match what you need